# Flutter GoRouter deep linking multiple parameters

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, url-parameters, flutter-go-router

I'm trying to do deeplinking in one of my Flutter projects using GoRouter. The link I'm trying to open has the following format:

**https://url/confirm?token=token&tokenId=tokenId**

The route I have defined for this type of link is the following:

```
GoRoute(
      path: '/confirm?token=:token&tokenId=:tokenId',
      builder: (_, __) => AccountConfirmationScreen(
        token: __.queryParameters['token'] ?? '',
        tokenId: __.queryParameters['tokenId'] ?? '',
      ),
    ),
```

The app gets opened when I tap the link on my phone but it does not navigate to the intended screen, I get navigated to a blank screen and I get an error saying GoRouter could not find a route for that url.
Does anybody have any idea how that route should look? I feel like I'm doing something wrong when declaring it but I can't figure it out.

[image]

Thanks a lot in advanced!

Edit: added screenshot for reference

Edit2: I've changed the route to this to match the expected route

```
GoRoute(
  path:
      '/confirm?token=5b85ad8ff63a53f1033c13389246b5b1b6502b634c305cc6d431a2688778e0e93d9d1875c1f5dbaef41c5a586033f5c751c8e17c61105b85d26531a16168&tokenld=64a9d5d5d41077baa0179d1',
  builder: (_, __) => AccountConfirmationScreen(
    token: __.queryParameters['token'] ?? '',
    tokenId: __.queryParameters['tokenId'] ?? '',
  ),
),
```

And I still get the same problem, so maybe the problem is more complex. Hope this might help.

Comment: Are you scrapping that url so GoRouter only gets after "https://url" and not the all the scheme and origin url?

Comment: Please write code in redirect function that prints the current path that GoRouter gets and add that path to your question. This would help to figure out your issue

Comment: I'm not navigating from a function, I'm opening a link from outside the app and being redirected to the app.
I am pretty sure that GoRouter only receives the part after the url, as the error on screen only prints the path starting with '/confirm?token...'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead:

```
GoRoute(
  path: '/confirm',
  builder: (_, __) => AccountConfirmationScreen(
    token: __.queryParameters['token'] ?? '',
    tokenId: __.queryParameters['tokenId'] ?? '',
  ),
),
```

and to navigate to that screen:

```
 context.go("confirm?token=${token}&tokenId=${tokenId}",);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, I still get the same screen.

Comment: is the path `path: '/confirm` or `path:
      '/confirm?token=5b85ad8ff63a53f1033c13389246b5b1b6502b634c305cc6d431a2688778e0e93d9d1875c1f5dbaef41c5a586033f5c751c8e17c61105b85d26531a16168&tokenld=64a9d5d5d41077baa0179d1',
  ` ?